# Beginner's book on website design?

Tags: php, web, responsive-design

I am basically a Software Developer, used C# previously but nowadays I am using PHP/MySQL. Right now I have got a job in a company where they asked me to design websites too. As I am not good in designing, but have no other way around. So can you help me in suggesting me a web design book that should not only teach me how to design a site from A to Z but also should give more tips and design patterns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I have got "Learning Web Design - A Beginners Guide" book. But I still make mistake and am criticized for not designing well.

Comment: In my experience, developers with little design experience absolutely love twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap is good and I have started using it, but when site design is too customized then boostrap goes out of control. I can't talk about, but is happening with me. I am also not an expert in it. Have been using it for over 15 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML & CSS - Design & Build Websites - Jon Duckett is one of the most famous books on design and a good book on quickly learning the basics of HTML/CSS

http://www.rakuten.com/prod/html-css/218664962.html?listingId=-1&scid=pla_google_rakuten.com&adid=17260&gclid=CNbwgMrZv70CFVQV7AodWB4AzA

But in order to learn the actual design patterns and concepts, I would suggest going to websites that hold competitions for brilliant web design, for example the Webby Awards or the CSS Awards. Additionally picking up books on simple design and color, whether that be in real life or on the web is highly helpful.

Regards

Comment: Actually CSS is not my problem. Bye the way thanks for http://www.cssdesignawards.com/. Actually my website designs don't look professional. I should say, I want a book which can put inspirations for designing great sites. I have checked out this book you are suggesting, its good too. I will try it.

Comment: I like book you suggested. Thanks